# “Object reference not set to an instance of an object.” error

Tags: c#

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    var par = obj as Parameter;
    if (ParameterName == par.ParameterName )  /* <=throws error at this code */
        return true;
    else
        return false;

}
```

I am getting this error when I am running that code: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

How to remove the error in c#?

Comment: @Amicable if `par.ParameterName` was null, no exception would be thrown.

Answer (score 5):

Principle **ONE** of defensive programming - **always** check for `NULL` !

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    // this statement CAN FAIL if your "obj" is *NOT* of type "Parameter"
    var par = obj as Parameter;

    // so therefore you MUST be ready to deal with a NULL value here!
    if (par != null && ParameterName == par.ParameterName)  
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if `par` is not `null` before accessing `ParameterName`

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    var par = obj as Parameter;
    if (par!= null && ParameterName == par.ParameterName )  /* <=throws error at this code */
        return true;
    else
        return false;    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about checking if it is null first?

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    var par = obj as Parameter;
    if (par != null && ParameterName == par.ParameterName )  /* <=throws error at this code */
        return true;
    else
        return false;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

ther'es a problem in your convertion to Parametre you have to check if null

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
   var par = obj as Parameter;
   if (par  != null && ParameterName == par.ParameterName ) 
      return true;
   else
      return false;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this for checking   `par  != null` null

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
   var par = obj as Parameter;
   if (par  != null && ParameterName == par.ParameterName ) 
      return true;
   else
      return false;

}
```